# Remove all non-numeric characters except one particular one

Tags: javascript, regex

Forgive me, but regex is simply beyond me.  I'm trying to use javascript to remove all non-numeric characters from a user input except the letter "m" in the first position.  I had this code which removes all non-numerics:

```
userInput.replace(/\D/g, '')
```

I'd like to modify this to not replace an "m" or "M" at the first position in the string, so

```
m490-333bA
```

would become

```
m490333
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
str.replace(/(?!^m)\D/ig, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
userInput.replace(/(?!^M)\D/gi, '')
```